# Interdisciplinary Algorithm Construction with Non-developers

Tags: algorithm, requirements, scientific-computing

Yeah, I know the title is a mouthful...

What I mean is to say is how do you communicate with a subject matter expert who needs a theory coded and tested?

For example, weather simulation is a collaboration between meteorologists, computer scientists, and software engineers.  The computer scientists and software engineers generally speak the same language, but he meteorologist is in a completely different world.

How do you increase the level of communication and understanding between disciplines?  And not necessarily just for weather, other sciences too.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the title to "Strategies for effective communication or collaboration with non-programmers"

Comment: Sorry Jeff, but your edit lost the main point of my question.  These are not business people wanting beans counted.  These are scientists who want theories tested.  The bland title you edited in did not reflect that.

Comment: You might at least want to spell check the title, I am pretty sure it is 'disciplinary'.

Comment: Close this question please, not related to programming.

Comment: @zamfir... How is requirements gathering not related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

The shortest possible answer is Continuous customer involvement.

All the pretty UML diagrams, crayola UI mockups, explanations-to-four-year-olds and other techniques will never give the full experience of using a working application. Keeping the consumer in the loop allows for a feedback cycle both to the client, and from the client to you.  This symbiotic relationship has the greatest likelyhood of producing a product that will be useful to them.

If you go into a box and come out with a product that you think they need it will likely be a whole lot of what they don't want.  By regularly demoing your product you limit the impact of any misunderstanding, so that you don't spend too much time going down the wrong path.

It can be compared to dead reckoning. If you blindfold yourself and try to navigate through an area you know, the error between where you are and where you think you are will accumulate with time.  If, however, you take off the blindfold periodically you can update your mental location.  There will still be an error factor, but you are eliminating the accumulating error factor.

Even if you think your communication/explanatory skills are top notch, you still have to account for error in the way they communicate.

Comment: I don't buy this... the algorithms sometimes run for days and produce a single answer.  What is it that I am to show them?  There is no user portion.

Comment: Whether it is a Gui, a process, a result, or an algorithm I think the principle is the same.  Work with them continuously.  Have them provide sample data for your algorithm that you can run quickly.  The sooner you can get them in the feedback loop the better.

Comment: +1: work continuously together on small pieces.  Waiting to get the specifications "right" rarely works well.  Iterative development; successive approximation; add details.

Answer (score 2):

**State Diagrams** work wonders for that task.  They allow you represent a computational process at a level suitable for the people you are communicating with.   The states hold a brief comment on what processing goes on there.  The arc between states show the conditions that cause a transition to a new state.

Having constructed the basic state diagram, you can move on to discuss the information that is being fed into the state machine.  This is where the persons domain knowlege ought to come into play.  Follow some data though the diagram to see the flow of how it gets processed.  Generally at this point, they start to notice other situations that haven't been discussed.

It may be necessary to drag in another white board, expand one or more of the states into its own state diagram.

Then generally, when they are comfortable with the flow, it's time to inject error handling into the diagram.

This technique has worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 1):

"The shortest possible answer is Continuous customer involvement."

I suggest you do this through some specific approaches.

1. A language in which you can develop quickly.  Python's my choice, yours may be different.  Java -- for example -- might not be high on your list because it takes a while to get stuff up a running. C++ may be too much effort for rapid development.
2. Build small things quickly.  Start with something -- anything -- that can get the conversation started.  Build, review, expand.
3. Formalize results with unit tests that allow you refactor early and often.

Once you have something solid, you can consider rewriting in Java or C++ or something to improve performance.

Comment: I was considering including links to RAD or perhaps Getting Real, but I opted not too.  My folly.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found that flowcharts are universally understandible, especially when representing algorithms. Flowcharts are generally easy to read and make, and are universally understood.

Answer (score 1):

I think what most of the commenters are missing is actually pretty crucial to your question - the idea that you're working with domain experts to build an implementation of their model to test their theories.

Most software engineering stuff out there is not about this regime - and like you say, this is just qualitiatively different than implementing some buisness process or building a server that has to implement RFCxxxx.

There are people working on this from both ends -- trying to teach scientists about the very basics of responsible software engineering (eg, Greg Wilson's [Software Carpentry](http://software-carpentry.org/)) and teaching software engineering people about large-scale computational science (eg, Steve Easterbrook's [very interesting blog](http://www.easterbrook.ca/steve/), from which [this](http://www.easterbrook.ca/steve/?p=1999) is particularly relevent).   Why things are as primitive as they are on this front, I have no idea.  Both have links to relevent colleagues on their blogrolls.

There are a number of important differences in this regime from stuff you may have been taught.  For one, the overall structure of scientific software is generally quite simple, but the subtlety is quite high - each line of numerics may be the result of 10 years of scientific literature in a number of fields.   Secondly, the whole idea of specifications kind of gets flipped on its head -- the specification is "accurately models reality" and what the scientist has is a model that they hope does that.  In a way, scientific code development is both implementing a draft specification and groping around for the real specification.

@vfilby sort of has the right idea - continuous customer involvement - but it's a little more than that.  For this to work, you are going to get put into the science loop - instead of the cycle being scientist → theory → test → interpretation → update theory, it's going to be scientist → theory → you code → you and scientist *both* interpret your own parts → update theory and/or implementation.   The domain scientists aren't going to know as well as you how to best implement what they want, or how to disentangle the results of their model from the results of your implementation of the model; on the other hand, they're going to understand the implications of the model much much better than you and how to update the theory.

This is a hard balancing act to get right. For it to work, both sides have to (a) respect the others domain of expertise, (b) learn a little bit of that other field, and (c) be invested in the project as a whole working.    These sorts of cross-disciplinary projects break down more often then they succeed, but they are vitally important.   I *really* wish I  had some easy, guaranteed-to-work tips for you.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the generic "business apps" answers that keep popping up.

Answer (score 0):

With great care and patience. You cannot assume understanding so use a technique like prototyping or pictures to communicate.

When the customer makes a statement you need to implement what you think he says, or draw a picture of it and show him. It is easier for him to recognize your misunderstandings this way. I would avoid long written descriptions because its very difficult to know if you understand.

The customer should not need to know your language, so do not try to teach the meteorologist the CS lingo. You need to learn his language. Even the most trivial requirement should be tested with a prototype. If they say: "We need to see a map of the US", then you need to draw a map of the US and show them and say "Is this what you want to see"? He's then going to say "But I can't see the mississipi river on this map" then you say "but you didn't ask for rivers" Then go back and re draw the map. etc etc.

I have had situations with much simpler requirements that went horribly wrong because the customer assumed that it was simple and I assumed that I understood.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with Weiger's stuff: 
  http://www.processimpact.com/reqs_book/reqs_book.shtml

Start by doing a vision and scope document:
http://www.processimpact.com/pubs.shtml#requirements

Answer (score 0):

You should always ask yourself, "How would I explain this to that ol' granny at the market?". Once you have that covered, you can talk and explain your methods and procedures to pretty much anybody. If they have some additional knowledge, even better.

If you can't, than maybe you should ask yourself "Maybe the problem isn't on their side.". Even if it is on their side, there is no harm in trying to understand their point of view.

Personally, I'm not a programmer by trade, but had never any problems talking with ones, as long as we both stick to the aforementioned principles.

Answer (score 0):

Act as a programmer, and use the "loosest coupling possible" approach.

For the meteorologist case, I know a little the field, and meteorologists and programmers hardly communicate on the actual code. Those programmers know enough math to implement whatever equations meteorologists want, and then meteorologists are geek enough to use the software.

I could also relate the traders vs quants vs programmers case, which is even worse...

They don't discuss meteorology, and they don't discuss code.